# ValueError:Could not find the input entity for PeerUser

Tags: telethon

I have an ValueError when I am trying to `GetFullUserRequest` in cycle from group participants.

My code is:

```
 dialogs = await tc.telegram_client.get_dialogs()

        for dialog in dialogs:
            if dialog.is_group:
                entity = dialog.entity
                max_users_in_chat = settings.TELEGRAM_MAX_USERS_IN_CHAT_FOR_DOWNLOADING
                if entity and getattr(entity, 'participants_count', max_users_in_chat + 1) <= max_users_in_chat:
                    participants = await tc.telegram_client.get_participants(entity)
                    for user in participants:
                        full_user_info = await telegram_client(functions.users.GetFullUserRequest(id=user.id))
```

And there is something strange with this cycle. This code works fine for first user in this cycle. But for the second and other users I have an ValueError.

I have tried to use `await tc.telegram_client.get_entity(PeerUser(user_id))` before using `GetFullUserRequest` but it didn't help. And sorry for my English.

Comment: Can you confirm that `telegram_client` is same as `tc.telegram_client`? and don't pass the .id when you have a user object, try with GetFullUserRequest(id=user)

Comment: Thank you so much for help. I've changed GetFullUserRequest to use user object and now it works.